# dynamic images will cause performance issue?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am creating dynamic images with canvas. I need a image with dynamic texts so with the help of canvas I had created the images (base64) and attached to the image tag this is fine. But when number of dynamic images is created i see in chrome <kbd>inspectelement -> Resources -> images</kbd>. All the dynamic images created are cached in the browser will this cause performance or memory issues in mobile or can I delete this once i had used. Any suggestion for this.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reuse the same canvas every time,

After using the canvas image, erase all drawing from the canvas

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Then again draw on canvas and use it...

Comment: I am converting the canvas to image using .toDataURL() this returned image is added to the image src. For Each dynamic image created with the new canvas element. clearRect only clears the canvas

Comment: yes you are right, 
then you should use the canvas directly ( if feasible for your project ) instead of creating an image from that canvas , this conversion may cause a performance issue in mobile browsers too,

Comment: if you are frequently creating image, lets say 10 to 15 time in a sec then it may cause the performance issue , else mobile os will free those memory after you release their instance , But to be in safe side you should clear the memory while next time image creation to get the performance you want..

Comment: I will try using canvas instead of the images and you mean to say that if usage of the instance to the image is finished os will free the memory itself.